# What is an experimental method that could be used to determine and measure impurities in a lens?

Tags: optics, experimental-physics

Part of my work (as a lab tech) is to check and double check the lenses we have to make sure that they are suitable for the experiments that my employers wish to use them for (as well as experiments we try).

Currently, our practice is:

- visually inspect the lens (ironically using another lens)
- shine a light through the lens, projecting on a white wall, and visually inspect.

But, what I am on need of, is an experimental that can 'map' out the imperfections, should they exist, in the lens - what is a suitable experimental process to do this?

Comment: Chemical impurities? Damaged spots on the surface? Opaque inclusions, like embedded dust grains? Color centers from radiation damage?

Comment: @rob yes, all of the above - any and all impurities.  I am not so much interested in mapping what type, but where the impurities occur.

Comment: You can use interferometry to map out the impurities.  They are very expensive, so that may not be that practical

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use a telescope to expand a laser beam to uniformly illuminate your test lens, and examine the interference patterns in the transmitted laser light.  (You can keep your same white wall.)  I'm not sure how much deconvolution you would have to do to convert the interference patterns to spatial information, but you can test it by experimenting with a known-bad lens.

Bonus points for using a laser near the wavelength that you want the lens to process.